# Regex match and delete everything before string (opening html tag)

Tags: html, regex

I'm using Dreamweaver and Notepad++ and have searched high and low but nothing seems to work from what I've found.

I've got a whole stack of html pages and I need to remove from all of them everything above but not including the first  tag in the document. Specifically, everything before the string `"<h1"` (no quotes). I've tried various examples in Notepad++ and it finds the first `h1` tag but doesn't replace everthing before it.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example?

Comment: `.*<h1` and replace with `<h1`. Make sure to tick the "matches newline" option in the find+replace in Notepad++, and select "regex" as the search mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assuming you want to lose everything in your file before the "<h1" text
then specify ".*<[hH]1" as search tag and "<h1" as replacement and check
the box marked ". matches newline". Works for me.
```

Comment: This works great - thanks very much and to the previous commenter. I tried </table>.* to delete everything after the ending table tag on each page and that worked too. I suspect I'd have a problem with pages that contain multiple tables. Not essential, but how would I delete everything after the _last_ closing table tag?

Comment: Just tested the code to remove all code after the _last_ </table> tag and it doesn't work as clearly it's triggered at the first occurance. How do I make it choose the very last </table> tag? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the Command Line or a text editor that allows you to search-replace multiple files.  However, are you sure the content is the same in every html file?

Comment: Well the content of the files isn't the same but I'm trying to automate wrapping the main content of the pages with new "header" and "footer" code. It's old code and it turns out if I can select and remove everything above the string {"<h1"} I can then deal with the bottom of the page and replace the footer code fairly easily. I think I'd prefer to do this with Notepad++ using Regex since I think it can do it for mutliple files. Thanks